# Combining results of two queries into one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to combine two queries into a single one. But I am not having any success in it.

Query1:

```
    SELECT
    District.PkLocID AS districtId,
    District.LocName AS districtName,
    COUNT(DISTINCT UC.PkLocID) AS reported
FROM
    tbl_locations AS District
INNER JOIN tbl_locations AS UC ON District.PkLocID = UC.district_id
INNER JOIN tbl_warehouse ON UC.PkLocID = tbl_warehouse.locid
INNER JOIN tbl_wh_data ON tbl_warehouse.wh_id = tbl_wh_data.wh_id
INNER JOIN stakeholder ON tbl_warehouse.stkofficeid = stakeholder.stkid
WHERE
    stakeholder.lvl = 6
AND tbl_warehouse.stkid = 1
AND District.province_id = 1
AND tbl_wh_data.report_month = 02
AND tbl_wh_data.report_year = 2014
AND tbl_wh_data.wh_issue_up IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    District.PkLocID
ORDER BY
    districtId ASC
```

Query 2:

```
    SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT UC.PkLocID) AS totalWH,
District.PkLocID
FROM
    tbl_locations AS District
INNER JOIN tbl_locations AS UC ON District.PkLocID = UC.district_id
INNER JOIN tbl_warehouse ON UC.PkLocID = tbl_warehouse.locid
INNER JOIN stakeholder ON tbl_warehouse.stkofficeid = stakeholder.stkid
WHERE
    stakeholder.lvl = 6
AND tbl_warehouse.stkid = 1
AND District.province_id = 1
GROUP BY
    District.PkLocID
ORDER BY
    District.PkLocID ASC
```

I have tried applying subqueries and joins but it is showing me incorrect results.

Comment: Sometimes two queries is ok

Comment: can you show what you've tried, and why you want to run just one query here - do you think it will be faster just because it is a single query?

Comment: I am thinking that one query will make the code simpler and easier for further data manipulation. Basically, I want to use the results, "COUNT(DISTINCT UC.PkLocID) AS reported" and "COUNT(DISTINCT UC.PkLocID) AS totalWH" to find percentage from these two within the query

Comment: It might be possible to merge this to a single query (eg, you could maybe use `COUNT(DISTINCT IF(tbl_wh_data.report_month = 02 AND tbl_wh_data.report_year = 2014 AND tbl_wh_data.wh_issue_up IS NOT NULL, UC.PkLocID, NULL)) AS totalWH` ), it would hardly be simple and easy to read code. Unless you hate the person who has to maintain the code, or there is something about the joins in this query that causes it to be VERY slow it is probably best kept as 2 queries.

Comment: Everything that is returned by your first query will be returned by your second query. Why don't you just use the second one? Or do you need the seperate counts?